# What is the difference between scale and fit in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science

i am new to datascience and when i was going through one of the [kaggle blog](https://www.kaggle.com/ashishgupta1992/houses-prices-dataset), i saw that the user is using both scale and fit on the data set. i tried to understand the difference by going through the documentation but was not able to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand the source of your confusion without any code. Inside the link you provided, the data is first scaled with `sklearn.preprocessing.scale()` and then fit to a `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor`.

So the scaling operation transforms data such that all the features are represented on the same scale, and the fitting operation trains the model with the said data.

From your question it sounds like you thought these two operations were mutually exclusive, or somehow equivalent, but they are actually logical consecutive steps.

In general, before model is trained, data is somehow preprocessed (with `.scale()` in this case), then trained. In sklearn the `.fit()` methods are for training (fitting functions/models to the data).

Hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Scale is a data normalization technique and it is used when data in different features are of not similar values like in one feature you have values ranging from 1 to 10 and in other features you have values ranging from 1000 to 10000.

Where as fit is the function that actually starts your model training

Answer (score 0):

Scaling is conversion of data, a method used to normalize the range of independent variables or features of data. The fit method is a training step.